# Possibility of using maven surfire plugin for SOAP webservice tests

Tags: web-services, maven, automated-tests, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a challenge of using maven surfire plugin for SOAP webservices testing.
What I need to check whether this plugin can be used while running webservices tests in CI environment.
Any suggestions are appreciated.

Many thanks for your comments and feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate) which easily integrates into a standard Java / Maven project. You can actually generate the standard JUnit XML report format which most CI tools understand. Or you have the option of integrating 3rd party reports via Maven. The test execution is via the Maven surefire plugin.

And yes, Karate has excellent support for SOAP and XML.

Disclaimer: I am the dev.